# Prevent firing of other scripts while fadeIn/FadeOut running

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have 4 different sets of script that fadeIn/Out several divs when clicked.  The problem I am running into is if you mash/click a ton the fadeIn/Out effects blend together.  How can I set them to fire only after completion of a FadeIn/Out cycle?

Here is my jquery scripts.  I can post the html if needed.

```js
// 1st Navigation


$("#1stforward").click(function() {
  $("#1st").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#2nd").delay(3375).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');

});



//2nd Navigation 


$("#2ndback").click(function() {
  $("#2nd").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#1st").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');


});

$("#2ndforward").click(function() {
  $("#2nd").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#3rd").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');


});




// 3rd Navigation 


$("#3rdback").click(function() {
  $("#3rd").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#2nd").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');


});

$("#3rdforward").click(function() {
  $("#3rd").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#4th").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');


});



// 4th  Navigation 


$("#4thback").click(function() {
  $("#4th").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#3rd").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');


});

$("#4thforward").click(function() {
  $("#4th").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#5th").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');


});
```

Comment: Chain `.stop(true)` before each `fadeIn/fadeOut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say they're all divs right? If so you can pretty much copy/paste this and it will prevent double clicks. I'm setting a timeout function for half a second, you can alter the milliseconds of the '500' to change as needed. It prevents pointer-events (such as clicking) for half a second.

It would be better to add a specific class to everything you don't want to be clicked and target this with the timeout function, but this should do.

```
// 1st Navigation
$("#1stforward").click(function() {
  $('div').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  },500);
    $(this).css(
  $("#1st").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#2nd").delay(3375).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');
});


//2nd Navigation 
$("#2ndback").click(function() {
  $('div').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  },500);
  $("#2nd").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#1st").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');
});

$("#2ndforward").click(function() {
  $('div').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  },500);
  $("#2nd").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#3rd").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');
});


// 3rd Navigation 
$("#3rdback").click(function() {
  $('div').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  },500);
  $("#3rd").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#2nd").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');
});

$("#3rdforward").click(function() {
  $('div').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  },500);
  $("#3rd").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#4th").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');
});


// 4th  Navigation 
$("#4thback").click(function() {
  $('div').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  },500);
  $("#4th").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#3rd").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');
});

$("#4thforward").click(function() {
  $('div').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  },500);
  $("#4th").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
  $("#5th").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing');
});
```

Comment: This is the method I ended up using and it works 100% of the time.

Comment: Thanks! This has worked nicely for me over time. Btw I updated my answer to have the timeout function set the pointer-events property to "auto" rather than "" (blank). The effect is the same, since "auto" is the default if there is nothing set for the pointer-events property, It's just a bit more complete since it doesn't rely on browser-based CSS property defaults. More info here if interested..

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_pointer-events.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to check if any element having `id` ending with `"back"` or `"forward"` is currently animated using jQuery `:animated` selector, or the `.queue()` `.length` is greater than `0`, if `true` do not call `.animate()` within the current `click` handler, else call `.animate()` at the element

```
function animating() {
  return $("[id$=back], [id$=forward]").is(":animated") 
         || $("[id$=back], [id$=forward]")
            .filter(function(i, el) {return $(el).queue().length}).length
}
```

For example

```
$("#3rdback").click(function() {  
  if (!animated) {
    $("#3rd").fadeOut(3500, 'swing');
    $("#2nd").delay(3500).fadeIn(4500, 'swing'); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `complete callback` support for fadeIn and fadeOut function calls. Read more about it here. http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

So the implementation should be like this.

```
$( "#3rd" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {

    // Animation complete
    $( "#2nd" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
    });

});
```